# Return all close match values in a Map

Tags: java

I have map where each key is a String.

To access a value I can use the `.get` method of `Map`. If I want to return anything that matches the key for example : `"one, onetwo, onetwothree"` , get all values that contain the String `"two"` so in this case return `"onetwo, onetwothree"`. Is this possible using a `Map` ?

Im currently using a List and iterating over each String and checking if the String contains the value I am searching for.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @James Montagne please see question edit

Comment: @user470184: so don't map anything? Just want to get the words containing your fragment?

Comment: @zeller yes thats all, I think the method I am currently using will suffice. I thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method on any of the `Map` classes (afaik). You can iterate the keys then check the containment of the fragment, or use a completely different data structure. A [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)-map would do it I guess.

---

Edit:
What you currently doing should be just fine for 99% of all cases. If you are processing extreme amounts of data, use [full text indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search). (Which can be done with [Suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree))

Answer (score 1):

Using a `HashMap` you will have to iterate over all keys and as soon as a key matches your pattern, then collect that value and keep going until you are done.
Using a `TreeMap` you can get the keys in sorted order so you could use perhaps this property for a more efficient search.
But I think you should switch to a different data structure. A `trie` as @zeller also points out seems to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

as others said there are no methods in the java collections API to acheive this.
this is how you do it by iterating over keys of a map

```
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("onesample", "1");
    map.put("onetwo", "2");
    map.put("onetwothree", "3");

    for(Entry<String, String> en: map.entrySet()) {
        if(en.getKey().contains("two")){
            System.out.println(en.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```